# Jdbi throws error when using reduceRows to join, one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, h2, jdbi, jdbi3, jdbi3-core

I'm trying to write an object query with JDBI to deal with one-to-many relationship. As seen in the docs, `reduceRows` is the way to do that. But I got these errors blaming the constructor;

**Update: keep one constructor for each entity.**

I tested a code from the docs and I got these stack traces:

```
get1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find column mapper for type 'join.AppJoin' of parameter 'c_id' for instance factory 'public join.AppJoin$Contact(join.AppJoin,int,java.lang.String)'
at org.jdbi.v3.core.mapper.reflect.ConstructorMapper.lambda$specialize0$3(ConstructorMapper.java:231)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:408)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.mapper.reflect.ConstructorMapper.specialize0(ConstructorMapper.java:230)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.mapper.reflect.ConstructorMapper.specialize(ConstructorMapper.java:189)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.result.internal.RowViewImpl.rowMapperFor(RowViewImpl.java:63)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.result.internal.RowViewImpl.getRow(RowViewImpl.java:50)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.result.RowView.getRow(RowView.java:35)
at join.AppJoin.lambda$get1$0(AppJoin.java:70)
```

My code:

```
import org.jdbi.v3.core.Handle;
import org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi;
import org.jdbi.v3.core.mapper.reflect.BeanMapper;
import org.jdbi.v3.core.mapper.reflect.ColumnName;
import org.jdbi.v3.core.mapper.reflect.ConstructorMapper;
import org.jdbi.v3.core.result.RowView;
import org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.SqlObjectPlugin;

import java.beans.ConstructorProperties;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class AppJoin {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("username", "sa");
    properties.setProperty("password", "");
    Jdbi jdbi = Jdbi.create("jdbc:h2:mem:testDB", properties);
    jdbi.installPlugin(new SqlObjectPlugin());

    try (final var handle = jdbi.open()) {
      String sqlc1 = "CREATE TABLE contacts ( \n" +
              "  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, \n" +
              "  name VARCHAR(255)\n" +
              ")";
      String sqlc2 = "CREATE TABLE phones ( \n" +
              "  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, \n" +
              "  phone VARCHAR(255), \n" +
              "  contactId int, \n" +
              "  foreign key (contactId) references contacts(id) on delete cascade \n" +
              ")";
      handle.createUpdate(sqlc1).execute();
      handle.createUpdate(sqlc2).execute();

      handle.createUpdate("insert into contacts (name) values (:name)")
              .bind("name", "str")
              .execute();

      handle.createUpdate("insert into phones (phone, contactId) values (:phone, :contactId)")
              .bind("phone", "1111111")
              .bind("contactId", "1")
              .execute();

      // List<Contact> list = handle.select("select id, name from contacts")
      //        .mapToBean(Contact.class).list();
      // System.out.println(list);

      System.out.println(get1(handle));
    }
  }

  private static Contact get1(Handle handle) {
    return handle.createQuery("select contacts.id c_id, name c_name, "
            + "phones.id p_id, phones.phone p_phone "
            + "from contacts left join phones on contacts.id = phones.contactId "
            + "where contacts.id = :id")
            .bind("id", 1)
            .registerRowMapper(ConstructorMapper.factory(Contact.class, "c_"))
            .registerRowMapper(ConstructorMapper.factory(Phone.class, "p_"))
            .reduceRows(null, (contact, rowView) -> {
              if (contact == null) {
                contact = rowView.getRow(Contact.class);
              }

              if (rowView.getColumn("p_id", Integer.class) != null) {
                contact.addPhone(rowView.getRow(Phone.class));
              }

              return contact;
            });
  }

  public class Contact {
    @ColumnName("id")
    private final int id;
    @ColumnName("name")
    private final String name;
    private List<Phone> phones;

    public Contact(int id, String name) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.phones = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public int getId() {
      return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public List<Phone> getPhones() {
      return phones;
    }

    public void addPhone(Phone phone) {
      phones.add(phone);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Contact{" +
              "id=" + id +
              ", name='" + name + '\'' +
              ", phones=" + phones +
              '}';
    }

  }

  public class Phone {
    @ColumnName("id")
    private final int id;
    @ColumnName("phone")
    private final String phone;

    public Phone(int id, String phone) {
      this.id = id;
      this.phone = phone;
    }

    public int getId() {
      return id;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
      return phone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Phone{" +
              "id=" + id +
              ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
              '}';
    }
  }

}
```

Gradle dependencies:

```
 compile "com.h2database:h2:1.4.199"
 compile group: 'org.jdbi', name: 'jdbi3-core', version: '3.12.2'
 compile group: 'org.jdbi', name: 'jdbi3-sqlobject', version: '3.12.2'
```

Would appreciate any help/someone pointing me in the right direction! Is ti possible to do that in a Dao interface ?

Comment: exception says: "Contact may have at most one constructor annotated @ConstructorProperties".
You have 2 constructors with that annotation

Comment: I kept one constructor for the entities and it shows `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find column mapper for type 'join.AppJoin' of parameter 'c_id' for instance factory 'public join.AppJoin$Contact(join.AppJoin,int,java.lang.String)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, JDBI requires always an `empty constructor` so for each entity you should have two constructors one empty and another one with your attributes, plus you should also register different mappers in your DAO using the annotation `@RegisterBeanMapper(YourEntity.class)`.

Here's a working example:

*main method*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Jdbi jdbi = Jdbi.create("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
    jdbi.installPlugin(new SqlObjectPlugin());
    try (Handle handle = jdbi.open()) {
        LegoDao dao = handle.attach(LegoDao.class);
        dao.createTables();
        dao.insertLegoSetWithTags(new Lego("75211", 2018));
        dao.insertLegoSetWithTags(
                new Lego("21034", 2017)
                        .addTag(new Piece("1", "vis", "21034"))
                        .addTag(new Piece("2", "wheel", "21034"))
        );
        dao.getLegoSetWithTags("21034").ifPresent(System.out::println);
        System.out.println();
        dao.listLegoSetsWithTags().forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}
```

*LegoDao*

```
public interface LegoDao extends SqlObject {

    String SELECT_ALL =
            "SELECT l.number l_number, l.year l_year,  " +
                    "lp.number lp_number, lp.tag lp_tag, lp.legoid lp_legoid \n" +
                    "FROM lego l LEFT OUTER JOIN lego_pieces lp ON l.number = lp.legoid ";

    @SqlUpdate("CREATE TABLE lego (\n" +
            "            number VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,\n" +
            "            year INTEGER NOT NULL\n" +
            "        )"
    )
    void createLegoSetTable();

    @SqlUpdate(" CREATE TABLE lego_pieces(\n" +
            "            number VARCHAR,\n" +
            "            tag VARCHAR,\n" +
            "            legoid VARCHAR,\n" +
            "            PRIMARY KEY (number),\n" +
            "            FOREIGN KEY (legoid) REFERENCES lego ON DELETE CASCADE\n" +
            "        )"
    )
    void createTagsTable();

    default void createTables() {
        createLegoSetTable();
        createTagsTable();
    }

    @SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO lego VALUES (:number, :year)")
    void insertLegoSet(@BindBean Lego lego);

    @SqlBatch("INSERT INTO lego_pieces(number, tag, legoid) VALUES (:tag.number, :tag.tag, :legoid)")
    void insertLegoSetTags(@Bind("legoid") String legoid, @BindBean("tag") Set<Piece> pieces);

    @SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO lego_pieces(number, tag, legoid) VALUES (:number, :tag, :legoid)")
    void insertBean(@BindBean Piece piece);

    default void insertLegoSetWithTags(Lego lego) {
        insertLegoSet(lego);
        insertLegoSetTags(lego.getNumber(), lego.getPieces());
    }

    @SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM lego WHERE number = :number")
    Optional<Lego> getLegoSet(@Bind("number") String number);

    @SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM lego ORDER BY number")
    List<Lego> listLegoSets();

    default Optional<Lego> getLegoSetWithTags(String number) {
        return getHandle().createQuery(SELECT_ALL + " WHERE l.number = :number")
                .bind("number", number)
                .registerRowMapper(BeanMapper.factory(Lego.class, "l"))
                .registerRowMapper(BeanMapper.factory(Piece.class, "lp"))
                .reduceRows(new Reducer()).findFirst();
    }

    default List<Lego> listLegoSetsWithTags() {
        return getHandle().createQuery(SELECT_ALL)
                .registerRowMapper(BeanMapper.factory(Lego.class, "l"))
                .registerRowMapper(BeanMapper.factory(Piece.class, "lp"))
                .reduceRows(new Reducer()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    class Reducer implements LinkedHashMapRowReducer<String, Lego> {
        @Override
        public void accumulate(Map<String, Lego> map, RowView rowView) {
            Lego lego = map.computeIfAbsent(
                    rowView.getColumn("l_number", String.class),
                    id -> rowView.getRow(Lego.class));
            if (rowView.getColumn("lp_tag", String.class) != null) {
                Piece piece = rowView.getRow(Piece.class);
                lego.addTag(piece);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

*Piece entity*

public class Piece {

```
    private String number;
    private String tag;
    private String legoId;

    public Piece() {
    }

    public Piece(String number, String tag, String legoId) {
        this.number = number;
        this.tag = tag;
        this.legoId = legoId;
    }
    // getter + setter 
}
```

*Lego entity*

```
public class Lego {

    private String number;
    private int year;
    private Set<Piece> pieces = new HashSet<>();

    public Lego() {
    }

    public Lego(String number, int year) {
        this.number = number;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public Lego addPiece(Piece piece) {
        pieces.add(piece);
        return this;
    }
    // getter + setter for all attreibutes exept pieces
}
```